# shortcode javascript not working on custom template file inside theme folder

Tags: shortcode, page-template

I'm using WordPress social login plugin shortcode `[wordpress_social_login]`.
I want to put it in custom template file inside theme directory.

example:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Social Login Page
*/
echo do_shortcode('[wordpress_social_login]');
```

so I create a blank page using this template, the rendering is ok but the button href become `javascript:void(0);` and it won't redirect.

i can't figure this out, so please help..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included `get_header()` or `get_footer()` in your template. They will load header.php and footer.php which *should* include `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`. Those last two functions are important because that's where scripts are loaded.

If your shortcode depends on a script being loaded in the header or the footer, then you *need* `wp_head()` or `wp_footer()`, thats where plugins load their scripts. Looking at the code for [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/) (tell me if that's not it), then the script for it loads in `wp_head()`.

So at the very least your template needs to look like this:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Social Login Page
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[wordpress_social_login]'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the plugin code, the only way it could've worked on your localhost is is you had not turned on the "popup" functionality, which requires the script.

Also, even if you're not using `wp_head()`, you still need the `<html>`,`<head>`, and `<body>` tags to be valid HTML.

Comment: but i don't want both the header and footer, just want a blank page. i tried this on my localhost and it's working, so dunno why

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: ahh.. I see. ok, it's working now! Thanks Jacob for your time and explanation. #bighug

Answer (score 1):

you are using a wrong syntax of `do_shortcode()`. Check [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) page for more information.

```
echo do_shortcode['wordpress_social_login'];
```

Replace it with this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[wordpress_social_login]');
```

try it. I hope it's useful.

Comment: oh ya thanks for correction, i'll update my question, but still not working

Comment: Please give plugin name

Comment: [Wordpress Social Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/)